# Disabling Mousewheel Bind

Tags: key-bindings, mousewheel, cloud9-ide

### I am Using Cloud9.io

I want to scroll **UP** the timeline in terminal but not go scroll up in commands when I move my mouse wheel up. I do not want mousewheel to function the same as up and down arrow keys. How can I disable the mousewheel bind?

Answer (score 0):

In Cloud9 mousewheel sends up down keys only when terminal is in applicationKeypad mode, where local scrollback is not available. See https://github.com/c9/core/blob/766fa74cbf/plugins/c9.ide.terminal/aceterm/mouse.js#L269.

This is useful when viewing content piped through `less`, (e.g when doing `git diff`)

But sometimes terminal can get into applicationKeypad mode when it should not. This can happen if there are some errors in bash configuration, or when sessions are attached to the same terminal, and they all have different window sizes.

Simply disabling this keybinding won't help to enable scrolling.
If you see this with one terminal session, try connecting cloud9 support, they may help to fix your bash configuration.

Comment: "... piped through `less`"
What does that mean?

Comment: gnu less program https://www.gnu.org/software/less/. try running `i=;while (true) ;do i=1$i;echo $i; done | less` in terminal